# Hash to array conversion

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

The following response is returned by an external API and is assigned to `ret_val`:

```
{:val1=>"add", :val2=>"delete", :val3=>"update"}
{:val1=>"add_name", :val2=>"delete_name", :val3=>"update_name"}
{:val1=>"add_city", :val2=>"delete_city", :val3=>"city"}
```

I want to convert `ret_val` into an array so that the values assigned to `val1`, `val2`, and `val3` can be extracted by giving `val1`, `val2`, and `val3`.So basically I would like to see key and value pair of all the comma separated pairs  .
Expected output :

```
val1 : add
val2 : delete
val3:update
```

till the last row returned by the API.
 Please suggest.
Note: API will always return response in above format only with duplicate key.

Comment: What exactly is the expected result of one of your example Hash?

Comment: Can you add example for one of the Hash to understand it better?

Comment: what you intend to do is not clear.

Comment: why so much down vote for this??? it is clear that API is returning this response and same is captured in one string , now I need to parse the string so that corresponding value can be set.

Comment: it is pretty clear that , if you do puts ret_val , it will return the response which I mentioned in my question. It seems to be somebody has edited my question and due to this it become unclear to other people. why do you want to brief this explanation? what is your purpose and what you want to achieve by doing this , it is unclear to me.

Comment: This question is already solved yesterday  by user2907032. Why do u want to put on hold .

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer: If you just want to reproduce the very same structure in JSON, you can just use Ruby's [JSON module](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html)

```rb
require 'json'

ret_val = [
    { :val1 => "add", :val2 => "delete", :val3 => "update" },
    { :val1 => "add_name", :val2 => "delete_name", :val3 => "update_name" },
    { :val1 => "add_city", :val2 => "delete_city", :val3 => "update_city" }
]

puts ret_val.to_json
# => [{"val1":"add","val2":"delete","val3":"update"},{"val1":"add_name","val2":"delete_name","val3":"update_name"},{"val1":"add_city","val2":"delete_city","val3":"update_city"}]
```

If you need to rework the structure, you need to iterate over the hashes in the response array, for example with `Array#each`. You can associate a block with the function and execute the block for each entry in the array. To illustrate, let's look at `my_array = ["one", "two", "three"]`

```rb
my_array = ["one", "two", "three"]
my_array.each do |e|
  # e is the current entry
  puts "The current entry is '#{e}'"
end
```

The output would be

```
The current entry is 'one'
The current entry is 'two'
The current entry is 'three'
```

In the same way you can iterate over the hashes in the array you've got from the API and handle each hash like you want to

```rb
ret_val = ... # same as above
ret_val.each do |hash|
  # do whatever you need to do with 'hash'
end
```

---

What you're looking for is probably [Hash#values](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Hash.html#method-i-values)

```rb
my_hash = {:val1=>"add", :val2=>"delete", :val3=>"update"}
my_hash.values # => ["add", "delete", "update"]
```

Comment: how it can be hash, a hash can't have duplicate keys. My code is giving error.

Comment: Now I'm confused ;) Isn't a hash like in the example what you get from the API? Or does the API return an array whose member items are hashes?

Comment: Yes, because duplicate can't be allowed in hash and to allow the same API is behaving like this.

Comment: "Yes" to which of the two possibilities? ;) Maybe it would help if you edited your question with a concrete example of what you get from the API and a concrete exampe of the structure you would like to transform it into.

Comment: currently I have posted only 3 rows but in actual response it were 30 rows. I can't  reveal   here  exact data for response so just shared dummy values only. After getting this values , I need to set this in JSON payload to update the operation .

Comment: It's still not really clear what you would like the result to look like. Maybe you could edit your question and add what would/should become out of the input example you gave?

Comment: updated question with more details.

Comment: now array format is generated properly by giving to_json but still  I don't get the expected values .After assigning ret_val.to_json to other variable val and printing val["id"] I am not getting desire result.

Comment: `to_json` gives you the complete JSON code, if its structure is supposed to be exactly the same as the structure of the API response. If you need a different structure, you need to iterate over the array elements like I showed you with `each` and do with each hash whatever you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

below code snippet will give you desire result:

```
#ret_val=calling API
ret_val.each { |x|  
x.each { |val| 
puts "#{val[0]} :#{val[1]}"
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks , Now I am able to get the desire results.

Comment: By seeing API response anyone can easily make out that it shouldn't be hash object as hash object  doesn't allow duplicate key.

Answer (score 0):

What the API is returning is a hash. You can access a hash value by its key.

```
ret_val = func()
```

ret_val is a hash object. To access its values

```
a = Array.new()
ret_val.each { |key,value| a << value }
```

Comment: It doesn't work and I am getting nothing with this.

Comment: API is returning Array so ret_val is a Array object as hash object can't have similar keys.